# Zipalign not working Catalina Mac OS , Bad CPU type in executable

Tags: android, macos, macos-catalina, zipalign

After the install of Catalina Mac Os I starting to see this error when I run zipalign

```
/usr/local/bin/zipalign: line 3: /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/build-tools/23.0.1/zipalign: Bad CPU type in executable
/usr/local/bin/zipalign: line 3: /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/build-tools/23.0.1/zipalign: Undefined error: 0
```

looking for solutions I found that may be related to the fact that catalina only runs 64bit apps and zipalign is 32, couldn't find a 64 bit version. any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, catalina changes the shell by default or something related to it, I had a bash script /usr/local/bin/zipalign, that fixed the run of zipalign to /bin/bash producing the error , so removed the /usr/local/bin/zipalign file and added an export to the folder that contains the file directly.